# Dask and Pandas giving different results

Tags: python, pandas, dask

When running the below code, I obtain different results.

```
import dask

# Loading Data
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

# Dask Computation
df.groupby("name").aggregate({"x": "sum", "y": "max"}).compute()

# Pandas computation
pandas_df = df.compute()
pandas_df.groupby("name").aggregate({"x": "sum", "y": "max"})
```

- dask - `sum(x)` for Zelda is 54.898716
- pandas - `sum(x)` for Zelda is
  100.269283

I'd like to understand where I'm going wrong in my utilization of dask

Comment: Can you include the dask version? I am unable to reproduce this.

Comment: show us your dataframe

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I'm using version '2022.9.2', also attached a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/vGRelRp.png.

Comment: @lagrangian_headache I can reproduce this result with 2022.9.2 but not 2022.8.0. I see there is a GH issue now at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/9535, so leaving it here for others to follow.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, that `.timeseries()` is based on random numbers. I think it still should yield the same result when called multiple times, like here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that results are not consistent due to the way the data is generated, for example:

```
# Loading Data
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

# Dask Computation
dask_res = df.groupby("name").aggregate({"x": "sum", "y": "max"}).compute()

# Pandas computation
pandas_df = df.compute()
pandas_res = pandas_df.groupby("name").aggregate({"x": "sum", "y": "max"})

np.allclose(pandas_res.loc[dask_res.index], dask_res)
# False
```

What about if I get re-load the dataframe from pandas to dask?

```
# Loading Data
df = dask.datasets.timeseries().compute()
df = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(df, 1000)

# Dask Computation
dask_res = df.groupby("name").aggregate({"x": "sum", "y": "max"}).compute()

# Pandas computation
pandas_df = df.compute()
pandas_res = pandas_df.groupby("name").aggregate({"x": "sum", "y": "max"})

np.allclose(pandas_res.loc[dask_res.index], dask_res)
# True
```